# different calculations for different subsets in r dataframe

Tags: r, subset, calculation

I am trying to add a column to my r dataframe, calculating dry weight from diameter (the diameter of multiple, growing objects was measured at multiple dates). The relationship between diameter and dry weight changes over time which is why I am using different formulas for different dates.

```
object<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
date<-c(7,8,9,7,8,9)
diam<-c(2,3,4,1,3,5)
df<-data.frame(object,date,diam)

  object date diam
1      1    7    2
2      1    8    3
3      1    9    4
4      2    7    1
5      2    8    3
6      2    9    5
```

Lets say I want to use the formula y=5x+17 for dates 7 and 8, and use the formula y=3x+16 for date 9. 
I tried this:

```
df$dw<-5*dw$diam-17[df$diam<=8]
```

but it tells me that there is different amounts of rows in replacement and data, which is of course true. If I could tell it to just put NAs where df$diam>8, it would be ok, but I dont know how to do that. I have tried using the subset function but haven't had any luck either. The only thing I can think of is making a whole bunch of separate dataframes - one for each formula, but that is such an unelegant (and complicated) solution!

```
# desired outcome
df$dw
[1] 27 32 28 22 32 31
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Will each date have the same number of measurements?

Comment: yes. I measured each object on each date.

Comment: The easiest way (depending on how many dates you have to calculate this for and what you want to do with the results) is probably to create columns for each date, and apply then you can just apply the relevant formula to the relevant column.

I'll get some code up in a minute when I work it out.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant, readable solution using dplyr's `case_when` will work for an infinite number of subgroups of `date`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate( dw = case_when ( date %in% c(7,8) ~ diam * 5 + 17,
                           date %in% c(9)   ~ diam * 3 + 16 ) )

#   object date diam dw
# 1      1    7    2 27
# 2      1    8    3 32
# 3      1    9    4 28
# 4      2    7    1 22
# 5      2    8    3 32
# 6      2    9    5 31
```

Answer (score 0):

One way (depending on how many dates you have to calculate this for and what you want to do with the results) is probably to create columns for each date, and apply then you can just apply the relevant formula to the relevant column.

```
library(tidyverse)
df$date <- paste0("Day", df$date)
df2 <- df %>% spread(date, diam)

#  object Day7 Day8 Day9
#1      1    2    3    4
#2      2    1    3    5

df2$Day7*5+17
#[1] 27 22
```

**EDIT:**
If there are only two formulas to calculate (as in your example above), an alternative, one-line and faster option would be:

```
ifelse(df$date %in% c('Day7', 'Day8'), df$diam*5+17, df$diam*3+16)
#[1] 27 32 28 22 32 31
```

Comment: There is more than 2 dates, so ifelse wont work. I am also scared of your first suggestion because I will inevitably struggle to get the dataframe back to some sort of order that suits me. So it seems even harder than separating everything into different dataframes and recombining it later. I was hoping to use which() perhaps. I tried that and even though it put a value into the correct rows, it didnt take the diameter from that same row. God knows why (I sure dont) :D Thanks though!

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? What do you want to get at the end?

Comment: I need to use the dry weight values to fit a curve.

Comment: you know what? I just figured it out. I am somewhat of an r newbie, so I decided to be quite happy with myself now. I guess that means I get to answer my own question on here, doesnt it?!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most simple or elegant solution out there (probably not), but this seems to work:

```
df$dw[which(df$date<=8)]<-5*df$diam[which(df$date<=8)]-17
df$dw[which(df$date==9)]<-3*df$diam[which(df$date==9)]-16
```

I played around with which() for a while and kept getting that error message that says there is a different amount of rows. I now understand that that is because I put a condition on one side of the <- but not the other.

Comment: Below you say `ifelse` won't work because there are more dates. Yo can use `>` and `<` inside `ifelse`.

Comment: The call to `which` is also unnecessary. `df$dw[df$date<=8] <- 5*df$diam[df$date<=8]-17`would do the same thing. This is called "logical indexing", since the TRUE/FALSE values of the logical comparison allow you to select elements of, or index into, the vector.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, now that you mention it. Thanks! Maybe this is a stupid question, but whats the point of which then?